# Pass a pointer to an array value from Cython to C

Tags: python, c, pointers, cython, ctypes

I have a structure in C that looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t id;
    uint8_t *buf; // pointer to message data
} msg_t;
```

and some function that receives that a pointer to such structure and modifies it.

```
void recv_msg( msg_t *msg ) {
    // Stuff happens to message here
    return;
}
```

With cytpes I tried something like this:

```
from cytpes import CDLL, Structure, POINTER, c_ubyte, c_uint32

class Msg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", c_uint32), ("buf", POINTER(c_ubyte * 10))]

lib = CDLL("this_example.so")
get_msg = lib.recv_msg
get_msg.argtypes = [POINTER(Msg)]
get_msg.restype = None

sample_data_array = POINTER(c_ubyte * 10)()
data = sample_data_array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
sample_msg = Msg(1, data)
get_msg(sample_msg)
print sample_msg.id, sample_msg.buf[0]  # Should change data
```

I'm getting a TypeError('expected LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 instance, got list',)

I've also tried a similar approach using Cython:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t, uint32_t

cdef extern from "this_example.h":
    ctypedef struct msg_t:
        uint32_t id;
        uint8_t *buf;

    void get_msg (msg_t *)

def recv_msg():
    # How I would do this I don't know
    print msg.id, msg.buf[0]
```

I should also add, I don't want use numpy (but would reluctantly if I have to). Also, the length of the data array can vary, but I also have a length variable in the msg structure, so I can initialise it to the right length for sending, and just set it to default values and max length for receiving.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: C does not support pass-by reference. It is **strictly** pass-by-value. A pointer is not a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm open to accepting other answers, but for now I thought I would post my solution in the hopes it might help someone else.

I solved it using cytpes and not Cython. **I would really like to see a Cython solution though**.

```
from ctypes import CDLL, Structure, POINTER, c_uint8, c_uint32, byref

class Msg(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", c_uint32), ("buf", POINTER(c_uint8))]

lib = CDLL('this_example.so')
get_msg = lib.recv_msg
get_msg.argtypes = [POINTER(Msg)]
get_msg.restype = None

data = (c_uint8 * 8)()
sample_msg = Msg(1, data)
get_msg(byref(sample_msg))
print sample_msg.id, sample_msg.buf[0]  # Should see changed data
```

Comment: Your solution is close.  I made some edits.  The type of `buf` is `POINTER(c_uint8)`.  What you had was equivalent to `(uint8_t*)[10]` in C.